# Merge multiple lines

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a file which contains multiple like this:

```
s10123-yyy.bkp.abc01.zone,Windows File =
System,N/A,defaultBackupSet,default,272188(* )(S =
),Completed,INCR,Mixed,02/28/2015 19:00:27,02/28/2015 =
19:03:06,02/28/2015 20:32:11,02/28/2015 =
20:32:09,12.08,53.93%,0.18,98.52%,0%,0.12,1:28:23,N/A,8.203,N/A,67303,0,8=
3,"Disk_Library2, Disk_Library6,",N/A,N/A,=0A=
```

Which I need to make it in one line like this:

```
s10123-yyy.bkp.abc01.zone,Windows File System,N/A,defaultBackupSet,default,272188(* )(S ),Completed,INCR,Mixed,02/28/2015 19:00:27,02/28/2015 19:03:06,02/28/2015 20:32:11,02/28/2015 20:32:09,12.08,53.93%,0.18,98.52%,0%,0.12,1:28:23,N/A,8.203,N/A,67303,0,83,"Disk_Library2, Disk_Library6,",N/A,N/A
```

If I do it manually, I highlight the "=" and press "delete" button twice to connect and get the desired result.
The last 5 character ",=0A=" needs to be deleted too.

Awk, Sed, Bash, Perl or Python script would be preferred.
Appreciate you help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most simple with awk<sup>1</sup>:

```
awk -v RS=',=0A=\n' -F '=\n' -v OFS= '{ $1 = $1 } 1' filename
```

The trick is to

- use `,=0A=\n` as record separator `RS`
- `=\n` as field separator
- have an empty output field separator `OFS`, so that the fields are printed directly one after the other, and
- force the rebuilding of the output record with `$1 = $1` before printing it.

**Addendum:** Obligatory crazy sed solution:

```
sed -n '/,=0A=$/ { s///; H; s/.*//; x; s/\n//g; p; d; }; /=$/ { s///; H; }' filename
```

I don't recommend that you use that; I just like writing things in sed that shouldn't be written in sed. It's fun!

<sup>1</sup> Tested with GNU awk and mawk, which are the most common ones. Multi-character `RS` is not strictly required by POSIX, though, so more esoteric awks may reject this. Thanks to @TomFenech for pointing this out.

Comment: awesome one liner...one catch is at the end, the comma is still there, like this:  `s10123-yyy.bkp.abc01.zone,Windows File System,N/A,defaultBackupSet,default,272188(* )(S ),Completed,INCR,Mixed,02/28/2015 19:00:27,02/28/2015 19:03:06,02/28/2015 20:32:11,02/28/2015 20:32:09,12.08,53.93%,0.18,98.52%,0%,0.12,1:28:23,N/A,8.203,N/A,67303,0,83,"Disk_Library2, Disk_Library6,",N/A,N/A,`

Comment: If that is always there, just use `,=0A=` as record separator. Otherwise, `{ $1 = $1; sub(/,$/, ""); } 1`. (Please tell me if it is always there so I can update the answer accordingly)

Comment: `awk -v RS=',=0A=\n' -F '=\n' -v OFS= '{ $1 = $1 } 1' filename` did the trick! Thank you, Wintermute!

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution relies upon GNU awk, as other versions do not support multi-character `RS`.

Comment: @TomFenech mawk also accepts it. Can't test BSD awk right now. It's true that it's not in POSIX, though.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, Create a list and then use the `extend` method to add the lines to the list, versus `append`.

Answer (score 0):

Through Perl.

```
perl -0777pe 's/=\n|,=[^,]*$//sg' file
```

Comment: It does not look safe to just delete everything that is not a comma.

Comment: it deletes only the last comma part. I though op wants like this. If no then you may consider this `perl -0777pe 's/,=0A=|=\n//g file`

Answer (score 0):

This is a Perl solution:

```
perl -l -0777 -pwe"s/,?=(?:0A=)?\n//g" file
```

- `-0777` disables input record separator, making the file into one single line.
- `-p` reads input from file and prints it back to standard output.
- `-l` (before `-0`) adds newline to your print statements.
- The regex `s/,?=(?:0A=)?\n//g` finds an optional comma, followed by `=`, followed by optional `0A=` string, and ending with newline.

I don't know if all your files are just one of these long lines. If it is multiple such lines, you should set the input record separator to `=0A=\n`, most likely, `chomp` the lines and delete `=\n`.

Answer (score 0):

sed

```
sed '
    :a
    /,=0A=$/ {s///; s/\n//g} # "end of line", remove the chars and newlines
    / \?=$/ {s///; N; ba}    # line continuation: remove the chars, append
                             # the next line, goto a
' file
```